# Get all work items in Azure Devops using GET API

Tags: typescript, get, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using typescript using GET API. I need to get/show all work items in UI. I have 4 work items in UI. I'm also using POST API to add a new work item to reflect both in UI and URL. If I add any work item in UI it should reflect in UI. Every time I add a new work item it is reflecting in URL and not in UI.

My GET URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids=1,2,3,4&api-version=7.0
```

How can I show all work items(which includes new work item which I'm adding). What should I need to change in URL?

I had tried changing the URL to

```
https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/wit/workitems?api-version=7.0
```

It shows 404 error. I'm not sure which need to be changed?

Comment: Why don't you use a client library like https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-node-api instead of doing it all by hand?

Comment: Many I know what is the use of this?

Comment: It is a package so you don't have to do what you are doing right now: hand building an API client. This is an already existing client.

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Comment: Sure, you can hand-code it yourself. But if you have to ask here for every single call you want to make, I am not sure how valid the "yourself" part of that is.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box Get API to get all the work items.

You can change to use the Post Rest API: [Wiql - Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#request-body) to get all work items.

For example:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{Organization Name}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=5.1
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems "
}
```

It will return all work item ids.

If you need to get details of the Work item, you can collect all work item ids and pass to the Rest API: [Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Already I'm  using a GET API to get the work items, POST API to add a new work item and another POST API to get all work items. I'm not getting the expected result.

Comment: You need to combine the two rest apis. Wiql - Query By Wiql is used to get  all work item ids,  and Work Items - List is used to get work item details

Comment: Do you mean like 2 POST API's should be combined?

Comment: I mean that combine the Post Request:  Wiql - Query By Wiql and the Get Request: Work Items - List. Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66214767/azure-devops-work-item-attachment-upload-date/66219505#66219505

Comment: I had tried by combined only GET request in worked POST is not working